# How to expand selected treeview node programmatically

Tags: jquery, treeview

I am trying to expand a parent node of a jquery treeview using jquery code.

I identify the selected (parent) node as follows:

```
var selectedNode = $("#treeViewSectors #" + nodeId + " span:first").parents("ul");
```

What I have so far looks like this:

[Treeview Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvcCm.png)

As you can see, the node q2 is selected.  What I would like to do is expand q2 using jquery so I can see its children.

Comment: Exactly which of the *numerous* treeview plugins are you using?

Comment: Ok, I admit that I am new to jquery and I assumed there was a native treeview but but I see now it is a 3rd party plugin.  I inherited the code and it seems that the plugin used is quite old and no longer supported.  So I will no longer pursue this question and will upgrade to a newer plugin.
Thanks for your response.